# Serenity BDD 1.2.2 Actions doesn't work correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer-11, serenity-bdd

After update serenity bdd on 1.2.2 from 1.1.34 Actions doesn't work correctly in Internet Explorer.

Method does not work:

```
withAction().contextClick(element).perform();
```

Enother example:

```
withAction().click(element).perform();
```

if alert is present after click proccess hangs and doesn't return from action click

Answer (score 0):

Serenity simply passes the Action commands to Selenium, so this is most likely a Selenium compatibility issue with your version of the IE driver or browser, or a bug in the IE driver.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Jhon.
I has understood. 
InternetExplorerDriverProvider return new instance with default DesiredCapabilities:

```
defaults.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);
```

Actions work when i put InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS true.